# Pass parameters to the constructor as opposed to methods other than the constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP and just wanted to know, within a class, when should you pass parameters to the constructor as opposed to methods other than the constructor?

#### Example where parameters are passed to the constructor

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct($a, $b, $c) {
        $this->sum = $a + $b + $c;
    }

    public function display(){
        echo $this->sum;
    }
}
$foo = new Foo(1,2,3);
echo $foo->display(); //Displays 6
```

#### Example where parameters are passed to a method other than constructor

(Credit to Geoff Adams who wrote this out in a previous question I asked)

```
class Foo {
    public function sum($a, $b, $c) {
        $sum = $a + $b + $c;

        return $sum;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->sum(1,2,3); //Displays 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you question is incorrect because it depends on the purpose of the class and your example is very abstract. But in common you shouldn't do any actions in constructor except initialization and yes it's better to pass initial data to constructor. Another approach is to use setters' methods.
Anyway I think it's better for the first variant you should use class with structure:

```
class Foo {
    private $a = 0;
    private $b = 0;
    private $c = 0;
    private $sum = null;

    public function __construct($a, $b, $c) {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->c = $c;
    }
    public function sum()
    {
         $this->sum = $this->a+$this->b+$this->c;
    }

    public function display(){
        if (is_null($this->sum)) {
            $this->sum();
        }
        echo $this->sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Your function names are very descriptive.  So should you initialize all the variables you plan to use in the class at the beginning of the class?

Comment: @LedZeppelin If you can do it you should do it. It helps you to avoid errors in future. As I wrote instead of constructor you can use setters like setA(), setB() and so on.

Comment: I gotta disagree.  For large classes, it's impractical to support extremely verbose constructors.  It will vary on the use of the class.  If a peice of data is necessary, then use it in a constructor and make it required so you never have an invalid object.  Don't put it in just because you can.  Do it if it makes sense to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no rule.  It depends on how you're going to use the class.  You can even do it both ways within the same class.